# How to use Twilio Proxy in Node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I've been trying for 3 days to properly setup a backend that will connect two phones anonymously for voice calling, with the help of Twilio. This is what I'm trying to do:

[image: 1]

I've watched the [live coding example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4DkZpapQJ8) and it doesn't work, at all.

1. I've installed the gem using `gem install twilio-ruby -v 5.25.0'
2. Entered the REPL
3. And started to follow the video:

$ irb

> require 'twilio-ruby'
>   client = Twilio::REST::Client('...', '...')
>   client.service.create(friendly_name: 'Test [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg2D7.png)')
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `service' for #

Ok ok, the video is from 2 years ago, it's fair that the SDK changed. So I followed the interactive tutorial that is available in the website, this one.

Before continuing... there is a [dedicated page](https://www.twilio.com/proxy) about the new Proxy feature, and in one of the sections there is the following image:

[image]

This is clearly Python, so here I go... I've installed the Python SDK, started a REPL and tried to follow the code... it doesn't work. Damn Twilio, update your things! (Or am I the stupid here?)...

Anyway... let's jump into the [node.js tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy), I'm sure at least the interative tutorial is working (so I thought).

So, I went to my console and created a service there, then I wrote the code:

```
import twilio from 'twilio'

const client = twilio('accountSid', 'authToken')

async function test() {
  // create session
  const session = await client.proxy.services('<MY_SERVICE>')
            .sessions
            .create({uniqueName: 'MyFirstSession'})

  // add participant 1 to session
  client.proxy.services('<MY_SERVICE>')
            .sessions(session.sid)
            .participants
            .create({ friendlyName: 'Me', identifier: '<my_number>'})

  // add participant 2 to session
  client.proxy.services('<MY_SERVICE>')
            .sessions(session.sid)
            .participants
            .create({ friendlyName: 'Me 2', identifier: '<my_number_2>'})
}

test()
```

Then what?

The docs say:

```
If your Twilio Phone Numbers are voice capable, you're now ready for a proxied voice conversation. Following the names from the previous steps, get Alice to make a call to her Proxy Identifier number. Twilio's Proxy service will then make a call from Bob's Proxy Number to his real number and connect the two calls.
```

It doesn't work... I've tried to call to the proxy identifier number, and it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what to do anymore, I've tried to reach out to them, nobody replies...

Comment: Is this Node or Python? Currently your question isn’t very clear on many levels.

Comment: Read again then...

Comment: @CharlieFish Twilio's tutorials are given in multiple languages, it looks like Faminha102 tried a few of them and could not get any working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the "node.js tutorial" and I can see how that can be confusing.

Here is what you can do to get this working and get a better understanding of how it works:

---

**Prerequisites:**

- You have a Twilio account and a Twilio purchased phone number. This Twilio phone number is going to be the "proxy" number.
- You have two other phone numbers from where you can make or receive calls (or texts), these are **your** phone numbers.

---

Step 1.

- login into your Twilio account and make note of your "ACCOUNT SID" and "AUTH TOKEN", they are on the "Dashboard".
  (https://www.twilio.com/console)
- go to the phone numbers page (https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming) and verify that you have a phone number there. It's okay if you just make note of the number because in this guide I'll tell you how to configure the main things via the console, not via Node.js code.

---

Step 2.

- still at Twilio, go to the "Proxy Dashboard" (https://www.twilio.com/console/proxy) and here "Add New Proxy Service" (there is a plus red round sign). Give it a name, click "Create" then on the next page, you don't need to fill anything, just scroll down and click on "Save"
- now you have a service which shows on the "Services" page (https://www.twilio.com/console/proxy/services)
- take a note of the service SID (KSxxxxx...)

---

Step 3.

- while still on the "Services" page (https://www.twilio.com/console/proxy/services), to the right side you can see "PROXY NUMBERS", it's a link, click on it to tell the service to use your Twilio number for this "Proxy Service" you just created.
- on the next page you'll see "This Service has no Proxy Numbers" and a button "Add Numbers", click on it and "Assign" your Twilio number.
- click "Close" after you see the message that the number has been successfully assigned.

---

Step 4.

- now you need to create a session for this service, go back to "Proxy Dashboard" (https://www.twilio.com/console/proxy) and you'll see your service listed
- to the right again, there is a link for "SESSIONS", click on it
- you'll see the message "You have no Sessions" and a button to "Create new Session", click on it and enter a name, you can select also the "MODE" (text, voice, or both)
- click on "Create" then scroll down and click on "Save"
- make note of the session SID (KCxxxxx...)
- now you have a service and a session

---

Step 5.

This is the step where you add the participants, which is about your two phone numbers. This part can't be done on the Twilio's console as far as I know. I did it running Node.js code.

You need to have Node.js installed on your computer (https://nodejs.org/en/), then:

- create a new folder
- in Terminal, change directory on the new folder
- run `npm init --yes`
- run `npm install twilio`
- create a new file `index.js`

here is the code for index.js

```
const accountSid = 'ACxxxxx...';
const authToken = 'xxxxx...';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.proxy.services('KSxxxxx...')
    .sessions('KCxxxxx...')
    .participants
    .create({ friendlyName: 'Alice', identifier: '+19997775555' })
    .then(participant => console.log(participant.proxyIdentifier));
```

In the code above, replace the values for

- `accountSid` // your Twilio account sid
- `authToken` // your Twilio auth token
- `KSxxxxx...` // the service id
- `KCxxxxx...` // the session id
- `+19997775555` // your first phone number

Next run this code to add the first participant, in the Terminal run `node index.js`

Last thing is to add the second participant, in the code above change the `Alice` to let's say `Bob` and also replace `your first phone number` with your second phone number, then run `node index.js` again.

---

After you added the second participant, you're ready. Now you can try to call or text your Twilio phone number (which acts as a proxy) from any of your numbers (phones) and the other of your numbers (phones) will receive a text or ring.

---

Note: the things that you did on the Twilio console, can be done with Node.js code, read the tutorial again and try to understand the steps and how the code works. If you need more help you can always ask another more specific question here.

Good Luck!